# Summernote and absolute path in the img-upload.php file

Tags: php

I'm using summernote as the text editor in a backend. The text and images stored must then be displayed in the pages of the frontend. 
The editor and the upload images works, but the problem is to recover the images in the frontend because of the path.
I need to use the absolute path in the img-upload.php file but it doesn't seem to accept it.

**img-upload.php**

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']))
{
    exit(); 
}
$errorImgFile = "./img/img_upload_error.jpg";
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
$destinationFilePath = '../../images/img-uploads/'.$newfilename ;
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destinationFilePath)){
    echo $errorImgFile;
}
else{
    echo $destinationFilePath;
}
```

with the relative path works:

```
$destinationFilePath = '../../images/img-uploads/'.$newfilename ;
```

but in this way not:

```
$path = 'http://localhost/sites/my-site/';
$destinationFilePath = $path.'images/img-uploads/'.$newfilename ;
```

I don't see any error. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured it out by now...

It seems Summernote does not render images from absolute paths, but the closest you can get is to specify the file from the root path, like:

```
$path = '/sites/my-site/';
$destinationFilePath = $path.'images/img-uploads/'.$newfilename ;
```

Results in something like:  '/sites/my-site/images/img-uploads/filename.jpg'

If you save this to your database, you can render your images anywhere on your site using this rooth path address for the files.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use Ckfinder or Fileman with Ckeditor. I made a repository for that. Go check it out.

https://github.com/senocak/Laravel-CKEDITOR-CKFINDER-usage

Comment: oh no, i don't want to change the editor right now that i'm one step from finish my backend...

Comment: okay but you should check this out to figure out how easy to implement. ;)